# API returns HTML response - how to extract value from Head > Meta tag by name?

Tags: karate

The HTML the url returns is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="I-need-this-value/>
</head>
```

I found a few similar questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758960/karate-api-testing-how-do-we-extract-values-from-content-type-text-html-kind) one seemed like I could store the response as responseBytes and find it that way, but that didn't work.

And then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330734/karate-assert-im-trying-to-extract-a-value-from-html) answer which I implemented like :

```
  Background:
#   call auth with shared scope
    * call read('classpath:util/auth.feature')
    * def dashboard = 'https://ourURL.com/dashboard'


  Scenario: get csrf-token
    Given url dashboard
    When method get
    * def responseHtml = response
    * def csrfToken = karate.extract(responseHtml, 'csrf-token.text=\\"([^\\"]+)', 1)
    * print csrfToken
```

which returns

```
14:05:02.696 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - failed to find pattern: csrf-token.text=\"([^\"]+)
14:05:02.698 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] null
```

I have tried storing the response as a string first:

```
    Given url dashboard
    When method get
    * def responseHtml = response
    * string responseString = responseHtml
    * def csrfToken = karate.extract(responseString, 'csrf-token.text=\\"([^\\"]+)', 1)
    * print csrfToken
```

but it returns the same error.

Has anyone done this before?

I also realize I could do this via the karate UI and tried to do it that way but also couldn't get it to work:

```
  Scenario: get csrf-token
    Given driver 'https://ourURL.com/dashboard'
    Then match driver.title == 'Dashboard'
    * def e = text('meta[name=csrf-token')
    * print 'e is ' + e
```

print statement is [print] e is null

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read further - [script()](https://karatelabs.github.io/karate/karate-core/#script) allows you to do javascript like document.getelement - etc

so for anyone needing to do this in the future

```
    Given driver 'https://ourURL.com/dashboard'
    Then match driver.title == 'Dashboard'
    * def token = script("document.querySelector('meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]').content")
    * print 'token is ' + token
```